# Error in Generating HTML Snippet for SPFX Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, spfx, classic

I have coded a webpart using SPFx framework, and am trying to add the webpart into the page layout to avoid any changes by the users. The site is using Classic Experience, and I have coded the Master Page and Page Layout with the help of Design Manager.

As per [Hardcoding a Webpart in Page Layout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245715/hardcoding-a-webpart-in-page-layout), I have exported the webpart, and upload it to the Webpart Gallery. However, when I go to my Page Layout->Snippets, and after selecting my uploaded webpart, it returns the following error

```
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

I also noted that Billy has encountered the same error at [Is there any way to have a static custom made SPFx web-part in a page-layout template you have created in Design manager (Sharepoint Online)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242094/is-there-any-way-to-have-a-static-custom-made-spfx-web-part-in-a-page-layout-tem)

Comment: I have the same issue, did you found any solution?

Comment: No, I haven't had any luck on this.

Comment: I removed this tag : Links="(Collection)" And it is working for me.